# Adiabatic free expansion

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, ideal-gas, adiabatic

Let us assume there is an ideal gas in a thermally insulated vessel and it is free to expand into vacuum through a small hole in the vessel.Would the mass flow rate be a constant? What would be the equation of force on the small hole.Which energy gets converted into the kinetic energy of the molecules if we assume internal energy remains constant

Here is the question statement
"Find the rate $v$ at which helium flows out of a thermally insulated vessel
into vacuum through a small hole.The flow rate of the gas inside the vessel is assumed to be negligible under these conditions .The temperature of the helium in the vessel is $T=1000K$"

their solution is $\sqrt{\frac{2\gamma R(T)}{M(\gamma -1)}}$

the answer should be

$\sqrt{\frac{2\gamma R(T-T_0)}{M(\gamma -1)}-{v_0}^2}$

I think

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 1):

If the gas is freely expanding to an evacuated chamber of the vessel, the flow rate will not be constant. It will be a maximum initially and eventually become zero when the pressure in the two chambers reach equilibrium.

I'm not sure what you mean by the force "on the small hole", but the pressure differential (force per unit area) across the opening will be a maximum prior to the expansion, and will  equal the initial pressure on the walls of the chamber where the gas began. At equilibrium the pressure will be no pressure differential and the pressure will be the same in the two chambers.

If the volumes of the two chambers in the vessel are the same, then the final pressure in the two chambers will be half the initial pressure. There will be no change in internal energy and consequently, for an ideal gas, the initial and final temperature of the gas will also be the same.

Hope this helps.

Comment: will the equation$PdA=v\frac{dm}{dt}+m\frac{dv}{dt}$hold? where v is the flow rate and dA is the area of the hole

Comment: Bob D, did you consider the possibility of choked flow?

Comment: @DavidWhite I was considering a simple hole with a shutter, not the throat of a convergent-divergent nozzle or a valve. But even so, wouldn't the fluid velocity still be a maximum initially and go down when the pressure differential goes down?

Comment: @Monocerotis Where did you get the equation. You also realize, of course, that $P$ is not a constant.

Comment: Bob D, if the hole is small relative to the volume of the container, and the hole is sharp edged, the flow velocity would be limited to sonic velocity until the pressure ratio of the pressure inside the container vs. outside the container got below 2:1.  Since the OP said that the air was flowing into a vacuum, I'm not sure of the point at which the flow velocity would decrease below sonic velocity.  And admittedly, declaring mass flow rate or volume flow rate in your answer would help.

Comment: @DavidWhite You know more about this than I do. But the  OP asked if the flow rate would be constant and if I understand you correctly, it might initially be constant until the pressure ratio goes below 2:1, but then would decrease. Is that correct?

Comment: @David_White what does being a "hole is small relative to the volume of the container" mean?

Comment: @hyportnex, if you have a cylindrical container with a hole equal to the diameter of the container, that is a large hole.  If you have a hole that has a cross-sectional area of 0.1 square centimeter in a vessel of several cubic meters, that is a small hole.

Comment: @BobD, yes, that is correct, but when sending gas flow into a vacuum, the calculation of container pressure vs. 0 pressure is non-intuitive.  Perhaps a "NASA type" could comment on this, as I am sure that NASA has done calculations on this.  BTW, in your response, did you mean volumetric flow or mass flow?

Comment: I mean the mass flow rate

Answer (score 0):

I found a convincing answer in this equation

$q-w=(h_e-h_i)+\frac 12\left(V_e^2-V_i^2\right)+g(z_e-z_i)\;\tag 1$

we plug in the values of the terms we know $q=0,w=0$(since it is free expansion)$h_e-h_i=-VdP$ from the equation $dq=dh+VdP$   $\quad K.E=\frac{m({(v+dv)}^2-v^2)}{2}$ and P.E=0

$VdP=-\gamma PdV$ as it is an adiabatic reaction.

this gives us the equation

$\int-\frac{\gamma cdV}{V^\gamma}=\int mvdv$

solution of which is the solution to the question.

Comment: Something seems amiss here. In order to determine if your "solution" applies to the actual stated problem, please provide us with a complete, unedited statement of the original problem.

Comment: I did that originally,but the question got ignored as a homework problem. So I deleted the original question and tried to post  a more general version.